# how to validate object schema where the fields depend on each other using ajv?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonschema, ajv

I am using `ajv` node package to validate my schemas. Supposed that a field holds an object type.

The object can have 3 properties: `"A", "B", and "C"`.

How do I specify that at least one of these properties must be defined and no other properties are allowed?

Comment: Are you looking for `oneOf`  ? Look for JSON-Schema documentation, not AJV. AJV is a JSON-Schema implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on if you want to disallow *all* other properties or just the specific other ones (if "A" is present, "B" and "C" are forbidden but "foo" is still OK) you can either use `oneOf` with the `additionalProperties: false` property or use `not` to disallow specific properties. Example for both:

schmema:

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {"A": {}},
      "required": ["A"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "B": {},
        "A": { "not": {} },
        "C": { "not": {} }
      },
      "required": ["B"],
    }
  ]
}
```

Note: The pattern `"not": {}` is always `false` so no value for the corresponding property can ever fulfill it.

This example uses `additionalProperties: false` for "A" so it matches

```json
{
      "A": 3
}
```

but neither

```json
{
    "A": 3,
    "B": 5
}
```

nor

```json
{
    "A": 3,
    "foo": 5
}
```

On the other hand, the example uses `not` for the "B" case so it matches

```json
{
      "B": 3
}
```

and

```json
{
    "B": 3,
    "foo": 5
}
```

but not

```json
{
    "A": 3,
    "C": 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `anyOf` for this constraint. The `anyOf` keyword allows you to combine constraints using a boolean OR operation.

```json
{
  "anyOf": [
    { "required": ["A"] },
    { "required": ["B"] },
    { "required": ["C"] }
  ]
}
```